# Disabling screensavers in Ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, server, screensaver

While monitoring performances on my Ubuntu server I've noticed these weird tasks taking up a lot of ressources: fiberlamp, xlyap, shadebobs

They seem to be a part of a screensaver package of sort which I've no interest in.

How can I disable screensavers using command lines?

Comment: On a newly installed Ubuntu Server, there is no X environment (no graphical desktop) installed.  So I dare say you must somehow have installed the utilities mentioned.  
You could try and remove the `xscreensaver` package, but as I tried it on my system, the response was like this:  
`sudo apt remove xscreensaver --dry-run
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'xscreensaver' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.`

Comment: @WillemK
I've removed `xscreensaver` using `apt autoremove` and this seems to have fixed it. No idea why it was installed in the first place, perhaps the server provider is responsible? Thank you in any case

Answer (score 2):

Remove `xscreensaver` using

```
sudo apt autoremove xscreensaver
```

This should fix it.

(As per [OP's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975360/disabling-screensavers-in-ubuntu-server#comment1564693_975360))